# Memory issues while doing fast sync with Ethereum main net

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, geth

I am trying to do a fast sync with the Ethereum main net using geth on my VM. I have 73 GB available in my diskspace, but everytime I try to sync it my disk is running out of space when more than 5000000 blocks are downloaded and only few blocks are remaining. The command I am using is "geth --fast --cache=1024". How do I resolve this issue. Additionally, if anyone could explain what --cache=1024 does, and what will happen if I do not us it?

Answer (score 0):

As of right now (Block 5700000), you need at least 150GB for a fast sync.

See [What are the Ethereum disk space needs?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-are-the-ethereum-disk-space-needs) for more up-to-date details.

`--cache` speeds up the sync. Depending on your RAM you can set it higher to speed up the sync.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/homestead-guide/blob/master/source/network/connecting-to-the-network.rst#using-geth):

> `--cache=1024`
>
> Megabytes of memory allocated to internal caching (min 16MB / database forced). Default is 16MB, so increasing this to 256, 512, 1024 (1GB), or 2048 (2GB) depending on how much RAM your computer has should make a difference.